# Slang Appellation for Plastic Surgeon?

Tags: slang, pejorative-language

Some years ago there were a few quite amusing, albeit slightly derogatory terms for plastic surgeons.
 A cursory Google has revealed but one: *Sellout*, which is a reasonable start. Others may exist, not noted in any of the old fortune lists, but in a book somewhere- or better,- in the memory of a subscriber willing to share.
Thanks.

Comment: Butcher springs to mind. I'm not sure why sellout would be a name for a plastic surgeon btw.

Comment: Thanks. Plastic surgeon specializing in mouths? A boucheter? :) Sellout is listed in this [thread](https://forums.studentdoctor.net/threads/surgical-slang.399226/). Perhaps a play on their popularity.

Comment: _Face lifter_ dates from the 1920s (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/face-lifter) but I know there's something more current. I just can't think of it.

Comment: thesaurus.com lists face-lifter and cosmetic surgeon. Only the first would be considered slang.